# You might just need to refresh it. Assertion Failed!: Provider type not supported : false Failing descriptor

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura-attribute, aura-iteration

Iam facing following error with my code:

This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it.
Assertion Failed!: Provider type not supported : false
Failing descriptor: {c:Picklistversion2}

can anyone take a look into this :

```
<aura:component controller="Picklistverion2" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" >

 <aura:attribute name="set" type="object"/>

 <div class="slds-text-body_regular">
  <aura:iteration items="{!v.set}" var ="d">        
 <lightning:input  label="Profile"  value="{!d.Name}" onchange="{!c. doInit}"/> 
              </aura:iteration>       
         </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller function for this :

```
doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
  //call apex class method
  var action = component.get('c.PermissionSetLst');
  action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
   //store state of response
   var state = response.getState();
   if (state === "SUCCESS") {
    //set response value in ListOfAccount attribute on component.
    component.set('v.set', response.getReturnValue());
   }
  });
  $A.enqueueAction(action);
 }
```

my Class for this

```
public class Picklistverion2 {
     @AuraEnabled
    public static List<PermissionSet> PermissionSetLst()
    {
         return [SELECT Name FROM PermissionSet WHERE IsCustom = TRUE AND IsOwnedByProfile = FALSE];
    }        

}
```

I want my query output inside my lightning input so that after i''ll move ahead for further conditions

Comment: You have some sporadic spaces in your markup that probably should not be there (e.g. `{!c. doInit}`. Please try fixing your spaces so that they look more like any of the code examples in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox you are the saviour for me to fix this error but it fixed the error but nothing happens. i want my class output but nothing happens.

Comment: @sfdcfox, in aura expressions, spaces are not a problem. Even `{! c.doInit }` is not a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `init` handler because of which the method is not invoking on init:

```
<aura:attribute name="set" type="object"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

<div class="slds-text-body_regular">
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.set}" var ="d">        
        <lightning:input  label="Profile"  value="{!d.Name}" onchange="{!c. doInit}"/> 
    </aura:iteration>       
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @salesforce-sas You are a genius it fixed my iteration part now values are getting displayed what i want but still one problem i want a drop down for my value and this input gives me separte input boxes for each output which is coming from query result. it would be possible if i get a picklist type option inspite of so many separtae boxes so that i can select each output query result and do further part.

Comment: i got the solution on iterating it like a option we can achieve this . Any way thanks all for kind help.